# Getting service handle or mount point from Feathers hook

Tags: feathersjs

I want to implement an after-hook that replaces record IDs with globally unique IDs of the form `{serviceName}:{id}` (where `id` is a typical MySQL numerical ID).

However I couldn't find a way to access `serviceName` or service mount point from hooks. Is it possible?

If not, I'll just stick with passing the service name as a parameter during hook instantiation, but that's manual and error prone. I expect there's a better way to do this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all services and then return the path for the one that matches the hook context:

```
app.service('myservice').before({
  create(hook) {
    const service = this;
    const allServices = hook.app.services;

    const path = Object.keys(allServices).find(
      currentPath => allServices[currentPath] === service
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: I didn't know `this` pointed to the service instance in Feathers hooks. Is that documented somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: It is. The pro tip in https://docs.feathersjs.com/hooks/usage.html says *The context for this in a hook function is the service it currently runs on.*